# ArrayList of type object in Java - Error which I can't seem to figure out

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a beginner in Java. The following code is me creating an ArrayList of type Student. I'm pretty sure I've done everything correctly, but the output is incorrect.

This is the Student class declaration:

```
public static class Student implements Comparable{
    public String first;    
    public String last;     
    public Integer ID;

    Student(String first, String last, Integer ID){
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.ID = ID;
    } 

    //@Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
     return this.ID.compareTo(((Student) obj).ID);
    }
}
```

This is the ArrayList created in main:

```
ArrayList<Student> arr2 = new ArrayList<Student>();
        arr2.add(new Student("ol", "rr", 123));
        arr2.add(new Student("iv", "tt", 321));
        arr2.add(new Student("ia", "bg", 456));
```

This is the line to display:

```
 System.out.println("Before sorting: ");    
 System.out.println("\nObject: ");
 System.out.println(arr2);
```

When I run it, there's no compile error, however, this is what's on the output screen:

Before sorting:
Object: 
genericsort.BubbleSortArraylist$Student@1db9742

I'm not really sure what's wrong. Can anyone see something I'm not seeing?

Comment: What do you expect to see? You print the array list. You need to iterate through the array and print each object if you want something more useful

Answer (score 4):

You are calling implicitly `toString` from `Student` - which comes from the one of `java.lang.Object`, since every Object inherits from that (and that is not an error).

Override `toString` for `Student` and it will look nicer, for example:

```
 public String toString(){
    return "first = " + first + " second = " + second;
 }
```

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I just *wonder* if the output that the OP shows is "incorrect" and there has to be 3 strings present. `ArrayList` != `array` (for which you would have to use `Arrays.toString`)...

Comment: @VeselinDavidov look at the implementation of `toString` in `ArrayList` - I *wonder* again if it iterates it and calls `toString` on each element and appends `[]` at the beginning and end.

Comment: at least the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) is saying it is so, and a quick check confirmed

Comment: @MartinMeeser nice! I did not bother to look at the documentation, as I know things happen like that. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are printing array object itself, so it prints hashcode of arr2 variable.

You should use :

```
arr2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And you should overrid toString for Student class:

```
public static class Student implements Comparable{
    public String first;    
    public String last;     
    public Integer ID;

    Student(String first, String last, Integer ID){
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.ID = ID;
    } 

    //@Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
     return this.ID.compareTo(((Student) obj).ID);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return first + " " + last + " " + ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: and he would need to override toString. Another option would be: arr2.forEach(student -> System.out.print(student.first+" "+student.last));

Comment: I think `arr2.forEach(System.out::println)` will behave the same as `System.out.println(arr2);`, check with [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()). That is why IMHO this answer is incorrect, and Eugens is correct.

Comment: @MartinMeeser you are wrong, Student class overrides toString method so it prints properties of students. I also tested it before posting.

Comment: @Emre overriding the toString() is the key, otherwise in both cases it will print Student@aaaaa

Comment: @MartinMeeser I already explain it in my answer so what is the problem in here? Aren't we telling the same thing?